# How to Preload Videos in Swiper Slides

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I am integrating videos in my slides (one video per slide) by using swiper (for angular). When swiping through the slides, it is very laggy. However, when the videos are already loaded, e.g. when swiping back to the video before, the swiping is smooth. Does anybody know how to prevent the laggy behavior? Is there a possibility to preload the videos?

Comment: any ideas? Unfortunately, in the api documentation only preloadImages is available

Answer (score 6):

Did you try this solution?

using - `lazyload.js`: https://github.com/verlok/lazyload

**Lazyload video:**
https://github.com/verlok/lazyload#lazy-video

> As LazyLoad doesn't rely on jQuery, you can use it in web applications
>   using **Angular**, React or Vue.js without the need to include jQuery. [Read More](https://github.com/verlok/lazyload#it-works-with-your-favourite-library-or-framework)

Works fine for me. HTML example:

```js
/* SWIPER */
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  loop: true,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true
  }
});

/* LazyLoad */
var lazyLoadInstance = new LazyLoad({
    elements_selector: ".lazy",
    // ... more custom settings?
});

if (lazyLoadInstance) {
    console.log("our lazy content is ready");
    lazyLoadInstance.update();
}

/* swiper events */
swiper.on("slideChange", function() {
    // ... do something
});
```

```css
/* swiper */
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

video{
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <video class="lazy" controls width="620" data-src="https://ak4.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1025732684/preview/stock-footage-two-male-colleagues-employees-cooperating-in-office-talking-working-together-at-workplace-smiling.mp4">
    <source type="video/mp4" data-src="https://ak4.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1025732684/preview/stock-footage-two-male-colleagues-employees-cooperating-in-office-talking-working-together-at-workplace-smiling.mp4">
</video>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <video id="lazyTest" class="lazy" controls width="620" data-src="https://ia800300.us.archive.org/17/items/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4">
    <source type="video/mp4" data-src="https://ia800300.us.archive.org/17/items/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4">
</video>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <video class="lazy" controls width="620" data-src="https://ak0.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1027882880/preview/stock-footage-young-entrepreneur-walkling-toward-city-sky-scrapers-dubai-urban-panorama-futuristic-digital-nomad.webm">
    <source type="video/mp4" data-src="https://ak0.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1027882880/preview/stock-footage-young-entrepreneur-walkling-toward-city-sky-scrapers-dubai-urban-panorama-futuristic-digital-nomad.webm">
</video>

    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <video class="lazy" controls width="620" data-src="https://ak1.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/25348301/preview/stock-footage--business-new-customers-sale-and-people-concept-thousands-of-people-formed-qr-code-crowd-flight.mp4">
    <source type="video/mp4" data-src="https://ak1.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/25348301/preview/stock-footage--business-new-customers-sale-and-people-concept-thousands-of-people-formed-qr-code-crowd-flight.mp4">
</video>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <video class="lazy" controls width="620" data-src="https://ak0.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/18238960/preview/stock-footage-young-girl-on-the-hover-board-on-the-river-water-jet-spray-young-girl-on-the-flying-board-flies.mp4">
    <source type="video/mp4" data-src="https://ak0.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/18238960/preview/stock-footage-young-girl-on-the-hover-board-on-the-river-water-jet-spray-young-girl-on-the-flying-board-flies.mp4">
</video>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <video class="lazy" controls width="620" data-src="https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1018564099/preview/stock-footage-two-friends-on-summer-vacation-or-holiday-run-on-wooden-boardwalk-on-alpine-mountain-lake-jump.mp4">
    <source type="video/mp4" data-src="https://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/1018564099/preview/stock-footage-two-friends-on-summer-vacation-or-holiday-run-on-wooden-boardwalk-on-alpine-mountain-lake-jump.mp4">
</video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>


<!-- assets -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanilla-lazyload@12.0.0/dist/lazyload.min.js"></script>
```

**Codepen:**
https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/wvwReJr

### Speed Test (gtmetrix)

**same videos

#### Lazy:

[image]

#### Without lazy:

[image]